# Error adding values to nested dictionary (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, elementtree

Ive been looking at parsing some XML data and placing particular values into a nested dictionary. After looking at the data and researching how best to parse the data I have decided XPath parsing is more suitable than child object parsing as, well it isn't structured correctly for child parsing.

So I am looking to move this data into a nested dictionary to output later. My first attempt to add a value seems to have worked but as it hits the first internal item I get an error. I think I understand the error correctly, I know strings are immutable in python but I dont understand why it works on the first key and fails on the second. Could anyone explain or point me to somewhere that does?

The error I am getting is as follows: `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment` this is on the following line `dictionary['host']['port'] = port`. As noted this approach seems to work on this line `dictionary['host'] = host`. **I would also like to note that Im not 100% sure this approach is workable, I am currently playing with ideas on achieving my goal.**

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

data_file = 'data.xml'

dictionary = {}
dictionary['host'] = {}
dictionary['host']['port'] = {}
dictionary['host']['port']['service'] = {}


with open(data_file, 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)

for node in tree.findall('.//address'):
    if (node.attrib.get('addrtype') == 'ipv4'):
        host = node.attrib.get('addr')
        dictionary['host'] = host
        for node in tree.findall('.//port'):
            port = node.attrib.get('portid')
            dictionary['host']['port'] = port
            for node in tree.findall('.//service'):
                product = node.attrib.get('product')
                dictionary['host']['port']['service'] = product
```

Comment: Please show an example of xml input

Comment: I will upload shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The Problem

There is nothing wrong with `dictionary['host']['port'] = port` on its own, but the problem arises because you are changing the value of `dictionary['host']` prior to the line in question.

```
host = node.attrib.get ('addr')
dictionary['host'] = host # <- here
```

> <sup>**Note**: After that point, `dictionary['host']` no longer refers to a (nested) *`dict`*, because the key has been overwritten with an object of type *`str`*. The object of type *`str`* is the indirect result of `node.attrib.get('addr')`.</sup>

---

The problem is easily reproducible by the below testcase:

```
>>> x = {}
>>> x['host'] = "some string"
>>> x['host']['port'] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: arr ok hmm, I guess the approach im taking isnt workable

Comment: Actually, looking at your error its on line `1` mine is as described further down at the line specified.

Comment: Excuse my stupidity, its because your in an interactive shell

Comment: ok I guess ill have to work out another way of doing this :(, thanks

Comment: @iNoob please mark the answer as accepted you are satisfied with the contents, and if you have a follow-up question do not edit this one, instead post a new one that takes another approach to the issue you are facing (writing code that works).